# Navbar occasionally renders in two lines

Tags: google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a strange behavior with using bootstrap's navbar nav. I have normal text and a label `span` in one of the navigational elements and the `span` sometimes ends up in new line thus rendering whole navbar higher than it should be. The strangest thing is that it happens only occasionally (~50% of the time), but without me changing any conditions (same screen size, same page/content, etc.). Also, I was only able to reproduce this in Chrome not in Firefox.

As soon as I use dev-tools to adjust any css settings, the `span` jumps back in place, so I'm really out of idea how to debug or experiment with fixes.

Any ideas or suggestions on:

1. how to debug the issuse?
2. what could be the cause?

Here is how it looks broken:

[image]

and how it should be:

[image]

And here is excerpt of my header. Unfortunately I have a lot of code in the full header (and it's an angular app some things are controlled dynamically), so I'm not fully excluding the possibility that the problem is somewhere else, but I'm having hard time reproducing it regularly with the full code, so I didn't think making a plunker case would be easy.

```
<header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top ng-scope">
  <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="divider-vertical hidden-xs"></li>
      <li id="home-button">
        <a href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li id="library">
        <a href="/library">Library
        <span class="small label label-primary label-super">new</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I think it's a browser compatibility issue, I suggest that you look for the css property that makes the span look in the right place, and see what is the prefix that you need to use to make it work in google chrome browser, here's some example : [Browser Support](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp).